# CORS Error : Deleting a record of a given ID using REST API

Tags: angular, rest, maven

In my code base, I am making use of REST APIs to delete a record for a specific ID. I subscribe to the delete service as below :

```
deleteScheduleViewService(id : number) : Observable<any> {
    let url = `http://localhost:8080/schedules/${id}`;
    return this.http.delete(url)
    .map(response => response.json() as any);
}
```

My REST endpoint in Java is as follows :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/schedules/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteSchedules(@PathVariable("id") Long id)
{
    scheduleServiceManager.deleteSchedule(id);
}
```

My key problem is how do I match an arbitrary ID with that of the delete endpoint URL. Do I put in a sort of regex expression and then extract the ID?

**Edits**

I get the following error upon trying to access the REST endpoint:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8090' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

**It seems like I am getting the Cross Origin Resource Sharing Error now.**

Comment: Enabling CORS, following the post http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-mvc-tutorial/cross-origin-request-blocked-spring-mvc-restful-angularjs.html

Answer (score 0):

To solve "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", add CrossOrigin to your controller class. For example:

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@Controller
public class YourSuperController
```